# Getting an interaction plot from a pooled lme model with mids object

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models, interaction, r-mice

Preface - I really hope this makes sense!

I ran a linear-mixed effect model using an imputed dataset (FYI, the data is a mids object imputed using `mice`). The model has a three-way interaction with 3 continuous variables. I am now trying to plot the interaction using the `interactions::interact_plot` function. However, I'm receiving an error when I run the plot code, which I believe is due to the fact that the model came from a mids object and not a data frame. Does anyone know how to address this error or if there's a better way to get the plot that I'm trying to get?

Thanks very much in advance!

```
MIDmod1 <- with(data = df.mids, exp = lmer(GC ~ Age + Sex + Edu + Stress*Time*HLI + (1|ID)))
summary(pool(MIDmod1))

interact_plot(
  model=MIDmod1, 
  pred = Time,
  modx=Stress,
  mod2=HLI,
  data = df.mids,
  interval=TRUE,
  y.label='Global cognition composite score',
  modx.labels=c('Low Baseline Stress (-1SD)','Moderate Baseline Stress (Mean)', 'High Baseline Stress (+1SD)'),
  mod2.labels=c('Low HLI (-1SD)', 'Moderate HLI (Mean)', 'High HLI (+1SD)'),
  legend.main='') + ylim(-2,2)
```

Error:
`Error in rep(1, times = nrow(data)) : invalid 'times' argument`

Note - I also get an error if I don't include the data argument (optional argument for this function).
`Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula`

BTW - I am able to generate the plot when the model comes from a data frame - an example of what this should look like is included here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3AH.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've included the only code I have for this issue.

Comment: @danielledamico you have included code, but haven't included the data or the `library` calls that would be necessary for anyone here to reproduce your issue and test / verify possible solutions (the output of a program depends on the data put in as well as the code). We need enough information to help you, but you have not provided it - please edit your question to make it reproducible - otherwise there really isn't much we can do to help, however much we would like to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it won’t be that easy. Multiple imputation object will definitely require special treatment, and none of the many `R` packages which can plot interactions are likely to work out of hte box.

Here’s a minimal example, adapted from [the multiple imputation vignette of the `marginaleffects` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/multiple_imputation.html) (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

```r
library(mice)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)


# insert missing data in an existing dataset and impute
iris_miss <- iris
iris_miss$Sepal.Width[sample(1:nrow(iris), 20)] <- NA
iris_mice <- mice(iris_miss, m = 20, printFlag = FALSE, .Random.seed = 1024)
iris_mice <- complete(iris_mice, "all")

# fit a model on 1 imputed datatset and use the `plot_predictions()` function
# with the `draw=FALSE` argument to extract the data that we want to plot
fit <- function(dat) {
    mod <- lmer(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width * Petal.Length + (1 | Species), data = dat)
    out <- plot_predictions(mod, condition = list("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length" = "threenum"), draw = FALSE)
    # `mice` requires a unique row identifier called "term"
    out$term <- out$rowid 
    class(out) <- c("custom", class(out))
    return(out)
}

# `tidy.custom()` is needed by `mice` to combine datasets, but the output of fit() also has
# the right structure and column names, so it is useless
tidy.custom <- function(x, ...) return(x)

# Fit on each imputation
mod_mice <- lapply(iris_mice, fit)

# Pool
mod_pool <- pool(mod_mice)$pooled

# Merge back some of the covariates
datplot <- data.frame(mod_pool, mod_mice[[1]][, c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")])

# Plot
ggplot(datplot, aes(Petal.Width, estimate, color = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Vincent- thank you for this. 
When I run the code, I receive the following error after here -- mod_mice <- lapply(iris_mice, fit) -- Error: Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list Called from: list2env(data) 
Do you have any insight?

Comment: Not sure, and hard to say without a minimal reproducible example using public data. But I added some new functionality to make this easier. I recommend you install the development version from Github, restart `R`, and check out this vignette: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/multiple_imputation.html